# Mongoose Schema Not Creating Fields with Default Values in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on a user registration feature for my React Native application using Express.js and MongoDB with Mongoose. I have a User schema defined with several fields including name, age, gender, and city, all of which have default values set to null. However, when a new user is registered, these fields are not being created with the default values in the MongoDB document.

user.js (Mongoose Schema):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  name: { type: String, default: null },
  age: { type: Number, default: null },
  gender: { type: String, default: null },
  city: { type: String, default: null },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

server.js (Express.js Server):

```
const newUser = new User({
      email,
      password: hashedPassword,
      name: null,
      age: null,
      gender: null,
      city: null,
    });

    const savedUser = await newUser.save();

    console.log('Saved User:', savedUser);
```

I'm missing the fields with null value in the server console output and mongoDB.

Here's the server.js console output with some example data:

```
Saved User: {
  email: 'Lkdlm@kcmld.com',
  password: '$2a$10$knk8jOidiFwnSSFm8QhQj.ndDefZ2oCiV81an6twgjMa2edhanwj.',
  _id: new ObjectId("64d7ada414deacac8e92c7be"),
  __v: 0
```

Here's the object in the mongoDB shell:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("64d7ada414deacac8e92c7be"), "email" : "Lkdlm@kcmld.com", "password" : "$2a$10$knk8jOidiFwnSSFm8QhQj.ndDefZ2oCiV81an6twgjMa2edhanwj.", "__v" : 0 }
```

Expected Outcome:
The newly registered users should have fields like name, age, gender, and city with default values of null in the MongoDB document.

Actual Outcome:
The newly registered users have missing fields or fields with undefined values instead of the expected default values.

I'm stuck on this issue and haven't been able to find a solution. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Verified the schema definitions in both the user.js model and the server.js file.
Restarted the server and re-created the database.
Tried manually adding a user through MongoDB Compass with default values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defaults doesnt run if the value is null or " " - [https://mongoosejs.com](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html). Only undefined works.